# How do I specify an outsize for gdal translations to an ENVI file?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm trying to create an elevation map using the output from gdal_translate.
When I run gdal I can convert to both PNG and ENVI and combine the results to make something like the following image.

[image: Mt. Rainier]

Here's the command I use:
`gdal_translate -of PNG -scale 23.000 4367.000 0 256 Rainier.tif Rainier.png`
`gdal_translate -of ENVI -scale 23.000 4367.000 0 256 Rainier.tif Rainier.bin`

That's great. In fact it's exactly the result that I want, except for one thing, 
I want to be able to specify an outsize. Let's say that I want the image to be 200x200.

Here's the command I use:
`gdal_translate -of PNG -scale 23.000 4367.000 0 256 -outsize 200 200 Rainier.tif Rainier.png`
`gdal_translate -of ENVI -scale 23.000 4367.000 0 256 -outsize 200 200 Rainier.tif Rainier.bin`

The PNG image turns out the way that I expect but when I try to utilize the ENVI map to change the elevation it gives me an unexpected result.

[image: Not Mt. Ranier]

Is gdal_translate -outsize broken for ENVI? or am I doing something wrong?

*edit: Adding image of the results after using `-r lanczos` while scaling in gdalwarp*
[image: Mt. Rainier with Lanczos resampling]

Comment: what is your input size (gdalinfo) ? this looks like a resampling artefact due to very different X and Y pixel size.

Comment: As @radouxju said, perhaps it would be better to specify -r bilinear (or lanczos or average).. it looks like the default *nearest* resampling method is causing some issues.

Comment: The input size is 446x325
Pixel Size = (0.002081390134529,-0.002081230769231)

I'll try using -r bilinear (or other) and report back.

Comment: Turns out gdal_translate doesn't have the -r flag, so I tried resizing the tif using gdalwarp and -r bilinear before using gdal_translate to turn it into a PNG or ENVI file.  
I also tried average and lanczos. The results were still messed up but now there's a peak on either edge of the tile that might match the peak that's supposed to be in the center? I'll add the image to the original question so you can see it. Do you think it could be offset for some reason?